# Find number of non-zero elements in a tensor along an aixs

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to find the number of non-zero elements in a tensor along a particular axis. Is there any PyTorch function which can do this?

I tried to use the [nonzero()](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=nonzero#torch.nonzero) method in PyTorch.

```
torch.nonzero(losses).size(0)
```

Here, `lossess` is a tensor of shape `64 x 1`. When I run the above statement, it gives me the following error.

```
TypeError: Type Variable doesn't implement stateless method nonzero
```

But if I run, `torch.nonzero(losses.data).size(0)`, then it works fine. Any clue, why this is happening or what the error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meaning of the error message - `TypeError: Type Variable doesn't implement stateless method nonzero` is, we cannot use `torch.nonzero()` on `autograd.Variable` but only on simple tensors. Also it should be noted that, tensors are stateless while the Variables are stateful.