# Count nonzeros element along an axis in pytorch

Tags: count, tensor

I have a `(32x750)` tensor

```
tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0043],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0043],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0044,  0.0000,  ...,  0.0044,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        ...,
        [ 0.0059,  0.0000,  0.0059,  ...,  0.0059,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0059,  0.0000,  0.0059,  ...,  0.0059,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0056,  0.0000]], device='cuda:0')
```

And I want to get  the number of nonzero elements along each rows. Something like that `[12  47 0 5 .... 8 7 50]`
This [discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/find-non-zero-elements-in-a-tensor/4493/2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857373/find-number-of-non-zero-elements-in-a-tensor-along-an-aixs?rq=1) didn't solve my problem and concerned the number of nonzero elements for `1-D tensor.`

Thanks

Comment: No code, no attempt?  Have you tried something?  Add to the question if so.

Comment: The links I gave in my post contain the code I attempted so far. No need to copy and paste what didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved using this [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/count-nonzeros-element-along-an-axis/19462)
I used: `750 - (tensor == 0).sum(dim=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Torch now has a `count_nonzero` function [built in](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.count_nonzero.html). This vectorized implementation is going to be faster than iterating over the tensor. It also supports counting over a given dimension.

```
> torch.count_nonzero(x, dim=0)
```

Comment: Is there anything faster than this?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_num_nonzero_in_each_row = []
for row in my tensor:
    list_of_num_nonzero_in_each_row.append(sum(row == 0.0).item())
```